# Implement Bloomberg BChain function in Python using blpapi

Tags: python, excel, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to implement Excel's BChain() function in Python. Unfortunately I have no idea how and if this can be achieved. Here is the function I want to achieve:

```
=BChain("COL US Equity", "LOANS", "LOAN_TYP == TERM")
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to implement =BChain() at the time of this post.

Comment: Can I retrieve the results that the above BChain() function gives me with any of the BDS, BDP, BDH? Unfortuantely I cannot find the related fields for the US Equity.

Comment: One workaround is to use BSRCH() - please review the help on this function.

Another workaround is to use BOND_CHAIN field, however, it will be deprecated according to FLDS<GO>, moreover, the returned bonds may not match =BChain().

Comment: @MouradBarakat
can I implement BQL in python , or even using any language please? or it just for Excell?